# Преобразование даты, содержащейся в строке, в datetime python

Tags: python, python-2.x, datetime

Каким образом дату вида `Mon, 26 Jun 2017 13:14:21 +0300 (MSK)` (строка) можно привести к виду `2017-06-26 13:14:21'?

Comment: Вам для каких целей?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

d = parse('Mon, 26 Jun 2017 13:14:21 +0300 (MSK)')
print d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')  # 2017-06-26 13:14:21
```

`parse` распознает в том числе и timezone:

```
print repr(d)  # datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 26, 13, 14, 21, tzinfo=tzoffset(u'MSK', 10800))
```

Answer (score 3):

Немного с костылем, который удаляет из строки последние два "слова", такие как:  `+0300 (MSK)`:

```
date_time_str = "Mon, 26 Jun 2017 13:14:21 +0300 (MSK)"
date_time_str = ' '.join(date_time_str.split()[:-2])

from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
print(dt)  # 2017-06-26 13:14:21
```

Для `python2` заменить `print(dt)` на `print dt`

Больше о формате даты можно узнать [тут](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 0):

Так как входной формат вполне стандартный, можно воспользоваться парсером из пакета [`dateutil`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/2.6.0).

```
s = 'Mon, 26 Jun 2017 13:14:21 +0300 (MSK)'
from dateutil import parser
dt = parser.parse(s)
print dt.replace(tzinfo=None)
```

Comment: @Barton был быстрее)

Comment: Зато я не пишу формат вывода)

Comment: Убираю, так как ТС написал, что хочет видеть на выходе.

Comment: Все, я понял. Но в итоге, если нужно сохранить в переменную, а не просто вывести через `print`, то нужно явно делать `str()`.