# Конвертация строки в дату python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть строка вида `'2020-07-22T16:41:35.521+0300'`
Как из нее получить дату в формате dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss?

Comment: datetime.strptime

Comment: а с какой маской?
если указываю (mystr, '%y%m%d %H:%M:%S') получаю ошибку 'time data does not match format %y%m%d %H:%M:%S'

Comment: план б. срезами

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_datetime.asp

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Преобразование даты, содержащейся в строке, в datetime python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/683850/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b2-datetime-python)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

print(datetime.strptime('2020-07-22T16:41:35.521+0300', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z').strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
```

Если кому-то прям совсем не нравится `datetime` можно через `re`:

```py
import re

s = '2020-07-22T16:41:35.521+0300'
yyyy, mm, dd, h, m, ss, *_ = re.split(r'[T:.-]', s)

# или 
yyyy, mm, dd, h, m, ss, *_ = re.findall(r'\d+', s)

print(f'{dd}/{mm}/{yyyy} {h}:{m}:{ss}')

# результат будет идентичный
```

UPD:

```py
from dateutil.parser import parse

print(parse('2020-07-22T16:41:35.521+0300').strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Так как формат вводной даты неизменный ([ISO 8601](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)), можно просто использовать срезы:

```
date_ = '2020-07-22T16:41:35.521+0300'
_____ = '0123-56-89-12:45:78.012+4567'             # только для определения позиций

dd = date_[8:10]
mm = date_[5:7]
yyyy = date_[0:4]
hhmmss = date_[11:19]

result = f'{dd}/{mm}/{yyyy} {hhmmss}'
```

---

*Результат:*

> ```
> '22/07/2020 16:41:35'
> ```